# Spring Data JPA Custom findBy not working

Tags: java, spring

Service where i call the method

```
public String deleteEmployeeByID(int id){
    if(employeeRepository.existsById(id))
    {
        List<Task> tasks;
        tasks=(List<Task>)taskRepository.findByEmployee_EmployeeId(id);
```

This error is raised

> 2020-02-13 12:15:32.707  INFO 20380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
>   DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 2020-02-13 12:15:32.707  INFO
>   20380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
>   Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet' 2020-02-13 12:15:32.741  INFO
>   20380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
>   Completed initialization in 33 ms 2020-02-13 12:15:33.628 ERROR 20380
>   --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   com.example.presentation.EmployeeService.deleteEmployeeByID(EmployeeService.java:101)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.example.presentation.EmployeeController.deleteEmployeeByID(EmployeeController.java:60)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:666)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_242]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_242]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242]

This Repository

```
public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Integer>{
        public  List<Task> findByEmployee_EmployeeId(int id);
```

Comment: Please tell us how do you wire employeeRepository or taskRepository in the service? Which is row 101.

Comment: Have you Autowired EmployeeRepository within your EmployeeService class ?

Comment: @Sachin Thanks Forgot to autowire TaskRepository

Comment: @LachezarBalev thanks for the help mate i noticed it later that i didnt autowired taskrepository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good if you have posted your related codes not just the doubted area seemed to you by chunk. 
Try `@Autowired` your service where you are using it and replace your method by this:

```
findByEmployeeId(Integer id);
```

Comment: yeah, i forgot to autowire taskRepository. Thanks